# PHP generated Excel file is different when downloaded

Tags: php, download, xls, garbage

I have a PHP file that generates xls files using the module found at http://pear.php.net/package/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer/

I can create the sample document just fine and when I open it, it looks fine.

My next step it to turn it into a downloadable link. To do that, I did this:

```
    $mimeType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    $file_name = "test.xls";
    $file_path = "/tmp/".$file_name;
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");
    header('Content-Type: application/' . $mimeType);
    header('Content-Length: '.$size);
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=$file_name ");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");

    // open the file in binary read-only mode
    // display the error messages if the file can´t be opened
    $file = & fopen($file_path, 'rb');

    if ($file) {
        // stream the file and exit the script when complete
        fpassthru($file);
        exit;

    } else {
        echo $err;
    }
```

When I download the file however, it contains a lot of garbage data both in Excel and OpenOffice. The diff says that then binary file in the /tmp folder and the downloaded file are different from each other. I'm guessing that it has something to do with the headers or with fpassthru but I haven't had much luck with debugging the issue.

Any ideas on what the problem is?

Comment: I would use file_get_contents() rather than fpassthru if you're simply reading the file contents and delivering them to the browser.

Comment: `readfile()` is better as it'll stream the file, rather than slurping the whole thing into memory. You can easily exceed the PHP memory_limit with file_get_contents

Comment: did u get the solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The multiple Content-Type headers are uncessary. You're essentially saying that the file is a muffin and a pizza and a ford taurus all at the same time. All you need is the `application/octet-stream` version, unless you want to serve up the exact mime type.

As well, is there any reason you're trying to turn the file handle returned by `fopen()` into a reference?

Try something simpler:

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=$file_name");

readfile("/tmp/test.xls");

exit();
?>
```

and see if that does any better.

Comment: I tried replacing my code with the given and it's still having the same issue. Also, I just copied the section of code that passes it as a reference so I admit that I wasn't sure myself on why it was being done that way. I tried it with and without the ampersand and it didn't make a difference in the output.

Comment: Have you looked inside the file with a text editor to see what the garbage is? Could be error messages/warnings from PHP, a stupid browser plugin mungeing things, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that you don't send ANYTHING out to the browser BEFORE the actual file content gets send.

It might just be some php 'error' or even 'notice' that Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer is producing and you don't even see. Or it might be a closing '?>' tag thats followed by s simple space or newline.

I had a similar error where the file that was generated inside the web folders were working. However the delivery using header('...') gave me corrupt files. This was due to a single space at the end of one php file after the closing '?>' tag.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same library and I just discovered that the files in the library itself are creating the whitespace.

Solution: In the following files remove the whitespace at the end of the file, or remove the `?>` closing tag at the end.

Files to edit (all files in the `Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer package`):

```
Writer.php 
Workbook.php
Worksheet.php
PPS.php
Parser.php
OLE.php
Parser.php
File.php
BIFFWriter.php
Validator.php
Root.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code at the top of the page where the excel file is generated

**ob_clean();**

This would clear all the gibberish data.Also check for any echo statements.If echo statements are present, remove them. The data should always present in format specified by excel package.