# Export to excel file give a warning message when try to open it

Tags: php, excel, export

Could anyone help me on how to remove this warning when I export Excel using PHP.

The file you are trying to open "example.xls is in the different format than specified by the file extension.

Here is my code , please specify where am doing wrong

```
<?php

// Start a session
session_start();

// Define variables from $_SESSION and $_GET
$firstname = $_SESSION['firstname']; 
$lastname = $_SESSION['lastname'];
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

$start = $_GET['start'];
$end = $_GET['end'];
$ProviderID = $_GET['ProviderID'];
$summarytype = $_GET['summarytype'];
$subspeciality = $_GET['subspeciality'];

$export = $_GET['export'];

// Connect to mysql db
include ("access.php");

header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; name='excel'");
header("Content-Disposition: filename=export.xls");
// Fix for crappy IE bug in download.
header("Pragma: ");
header("Cache-Control: ");

error_reporting("E_ALL");

$sql = "SELECT *, master.EmtracSigChange AS 'SigChange' FROM master, nightrad WHERE master.EmtracSigChange='Yes' AND master.MaryGrade!='' AND master.InternalExamID=nightrad.InternalExamID AND master.TranscriptionDTTM <= '$end' AND master.TranscriptionDTTM >= '$start'";

$result = mysql_db_query('testDb',$sql);

if(!$result) {
echo "<p>No matches to your query</p>";
echo "<p>Click back on your browser to change your query parameters.</p>";
die(mysql_error());
}

?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<th bgcolor="#0099FF" scope="col">Accession</th>
<th bgcolor="#0099FF" scope="col">Transcribed</th>
<th bgcolor="#0099FF" scope="col">Turnaround time</th>
<th bgcolor="#0099FF" scope="col">Attending</th>
<th bgcolor="#0099FF" scope="col">Res or fellow</th>
<th bgcolor="#0099FF" scope="col">Modality</th>
<th bgcolor="#0099FF" scope="col">Exam</th>
<th bgcolor="#0099FF" scope="col">Discrepancy</th>
<th bgcolor="#0099FF" scope="col">Folder</th>
<th bgcolor="#0099FF" scope="col">Comment</th>
</tr>
<?php 
// Add all values in the table to $out.
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$CompletedDTTM = $row['CompletedDTTM'];
$TranscriptionDTTM = $row['TranscriptionDTTM'];
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($TranscriptionDTTM));

// Converting turnaround time from DTTM to time
$parsedtime = strtotime($CompletedDTTM . " GMT");
$convertedtime = gmdate("H:i:s", $parsedtime);

$parsedtime1 = strtotime($TranscriptionDTTM . " GMT");
$convertedtime1 = gmdate("H:i:s", $parsedtime1);
$parsedtat = $parsedtime1 - $parsedtime;
$turnaroundtime = gmdate("H:i", $parsedtat);

?>
<tr >
<td><?php echo $row['AccessionNumber']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $date; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $turnaroundtime; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['AttendingLastName']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['LastName']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['Modality']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['ExamDesc']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['MaryGrade']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['MaryFolder']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['MaryComment'] ?></td>

</tr>

<?php
}      
?>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

It gives me data but the issue is when i try to open it shows warning message also.Please Help

Comment: You are outputting html into xls file.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704340/php-generated-excel-file-is-different-when-downloaded). See if it helps.

Comment: `please specify where am doing wrong`... what your're doing wrong is writing a file with a .xls extension that is not actually and .xls (BIFF) content, but HTML content.... MS Excel is quite forgiving, and allows this, but it does remind you that what you've done is wrong. The solution is either to write a .html file with your html markup, or to write an Excel BIFF file content with a .xls extension (or an OfficeOpenXML file with a .xlsx extension) using one of the many PHP libraries around such as PHPExcel that creates the correct content format, or to write a CSV file with a .csv extension.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your are outputting HTML into an excel file. I would suggest you to use [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function to output CSV value. And use following for content-type:

```
  header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= export.csv');
```

Comment: It is export as csv file that we can open in excel but i need a excel file itself

Comment: See comment by @MarkBaker: `what your're doing wrong is writing a file with a .xls extension that is not actually and .xls (BIFF) content, but HTML content`

Answer (score 0):

You can download using CSV. But if you want exact Excel then please have look at below reference 
http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home

phpexcel will let you to download in different format. But still it was slow on large data. So are you the ccorePHP code builder then go far below example.

```
<?php

function xlsBOF() {
    echo pack("ssssss", 0x809, 0x8, 0x0, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0);
}
function xlsEOF() {
    echo pack("ss", 0x0A, 0x00);
}
function xlsWriteNumber($Row, $Col, $Value) {
    echo pack("sssss", 0x203, 14, $Row, $Col, 0x0);
    echo pack("d", $Value);
}
function xlsWriteLabel($Row, $Col, $Value) {
    $L = strlen($Value);
    echo pack("ssssss", 0x204, 8 + $L, $Row, $Col, 0x0, $L);
    echo $Value;
} 
// prepare headers information
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"export_".date("Y-m-d").".xls\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
// start exporting
xlsBOF();
// first row 
xlsWriteLabel(0, 0, "id");
xlsWriteLabel(0, 1, "name");
xlsWriteLabel(0, 2, "email");
// second row 
xlsWriteNumber(1, 0, 230);
xlsWriteLabel(1, 1, "John");
xlsWriteLabel(1, 2, "john@yahoo.com");
// third row 
xlsWriteNumber(2, 0, 350);
xlsWriteLabel(2, 1, "Mark");
xlsWriteLabel(2, 2, "mark@yahoo.com");
// end exporting
xlsEOF();
exit;

?>
```

Reference from http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/php-export-mysql-data-to-xls-file